# How can I efficiently sort a large dataset in Python while minimizing memory usage?

Tags: python, database

I am working on a Python project that involves sorting a very large dataset, but I am running into memory issues when attempting to do so. The dataset consists of approximately 100 million records, and is currently stored in a CSV file. Each record contains multiple fields, such as a timestamp, a numeric value, and several categorical variables.

I am looking for a more memory-efficient way to sort this dataset in Python. Ideally, I would like to avoid loading the entire dataset into memory at once, and instead sort it in smaller, more manageable chunks. I am also open to using external libraries or tools if they are better suited to this task.

I am running this code on a machine with 16 GB of RAM and a quad-core processor. I am using Python 3.9.7 on Windows 10.

I have attempted to use Python's built-in sorted() function to sort the dataset, but I am encountering memory errors due to the size of the dataset. Specifically, I am running out of memory when attempting to load the entire dataset into memory in order to sort it.

Comment: Which column are you trying to sort by?  One column or multiple?  Please post your code

Comment: Just to be clear, your memory issue happens when you "load" your data, not when you wort it, right? Sorting is at the moment, just the objective... How are you loading this data? Is a layer like pandas involved, are you using a dictReader, a csvReader, something else?

Comment: How is the sort key determined? Can you give a few example of candidate keys?